# Coloring a path in a circuit

Tags: color, circuitikz

I have edited my code according to the answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}

\draw (0,2.5)                   node (H) [label={[xshift=-2ex]H}]{}
to[R={r}](5,2.5)                node (D) [label={[yshift=2ex]D}]{}
to[C={$C_1$}](10,2.5)           node (C) [label={[yshift=2ex]C}]{}
to[C={$C_2$}](15,2.5)           node (G) [label={[xshift=2ex]G}]{}
to[battery1=$E_4$](15,-2.5)     node (F) [label={[xshift=2ex]F}]{}
to[R={r}](10,-2.5)              node (B) [label={[yshift=-4ex]B}]{}
to[R={r}](5,-2.5)               node (A) [label={[yshift=-4ex]A}]{}
to[C={$C_3$}](0,-2.5)           node (E) [label={[xshift=-2ex]E}]{}
(0,2.5) to[battery1=$E_3$](0,-2.5) 
(5,2.5) to[battery1=$E_1$](5,-2.5)
(10,2.5)to[battery1=$E_2$](10,-2.5)
(0,2.5)to[short](0,7.5)
(15,2.5)to[short](15,7.5)
(0,-2.5)to[short](0,-7.5)
(15,-2.5)to[short](15,-7.5)
(0,7.5)to[R={r}](15,7.5)
(0,-7.5)to[C={$C_4$}](15,-7.5);


\draw [red] (D)--(A)--(F)--(15,7.5)--(0,7.5)--(0,2.5)--(D);


\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Which will create the following circuit. There is a gap in the nodes D,A,F. How do I fill it up? How can I make an animation showing the flow of current?

Comment: What do you want to do with that path? Color it? including elements? Just wires?

Comment: I want to color it

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}[
    every node/.style={inner sep = 0pt, outer sep = 0}
  ]

\draw (0,2.5)                   node (H) [label={[xshift=-2ex]H}]{}
to[R={r}](5,2.5)                node (D) [label={[yshift=2ex]D}]{}
to[C={$C_1$}](10,2.5)           node (C) [label={[yshift=2ex]C}]{}
to[C={$C_2$}](15,2.5)           node (G) [label={[xshift=2ex]G}]{}
to[battery1=$E_4$](15,-2.5)     node (F) [label={[xshift=2ex]F}]{}
to[R={r}](10,-2.5)              node (B) [label={[yshift=-3ex]B}]{}
to[R={r}](5,-2.5)               node (A) [label={[yshift=-3ex]A}]{}
to[C={$C_3$}](0,-2.5)           node (E) [label={[xshift=-2ex]E}]{}
(0,2.5) to[battery1=$E_3$](0,-2.5)
(5,2.5) to[battery1=$E_1$](5,-2.5)
(10,2.5)to[battery1=$E_2$](10,-2.5)
(0,2.5)to[short](0,7.5)
(15,2.5)to[short](15,7.5)
(0,-2.5)to[short](0,-7.5)
(15,-2.5)to[short](15,-7.5)
(0,7.5)to[R={r}](15,7.5)
(0,-7.5)to[C={$C_4$}](15,-7.5);

\draw[red, opacity = 0.3, line width = 3pt] (A) rectangle (G);


\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And of course ...

[image]